# Output of a pointer based program

Tags: c++

I was asked this question in my interview. I am a newbie in C++ and this program compiles successfully. Could anyone please tell me what exactly this program does?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student {
   private:
      char *name;
};
int main() {
   Student *s = new Student();
   Student s1 = *s;
   Student s2;
   s2 = s1;
   delete s;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think it does?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you think it does, then we'll correct you if you're wrong. You'll learn better that way.

Comment: This is C++, btw, not C.

Comment: `Could anyone please tell me what exactly this program does?`  We have no idea what your real level of knowledge is.  Do you know what `main()` is?  Do you know what a `class` is?  Do you know what member variables are?  Do you know what `new` does?  Etc..etc.. So it makes no sense to ask "what this program does" until you tell us what particular part of the program you don't understand.

Comment: I think we area making a pointer type object and copying the value of pointer *s into s1. Similarly in the next step s2 = s1, we are putting the value of s1 into s2.

Comment: Short answer: Nothing. Longer answer: Nothing useful or nothing harmful besides wasting CPU cycles and allocations (if not optimized away)

Answer (score 1):

For classes with no user-defined assignment operator (copy constructor), compiler generates the default one (ones), which assigns (copies) all members by simple assignment. So, in case of student, default `operator=` would look like this:

```
Student& operator=(const Strudent& rhs)
{
    this->name = rhs.name;
}
```

While copy constructor:

```
Student(const Student& origin)
: name(origin.name)
{
}
```

This means, that just before this line:

```
delete s;
```

`s`, `s1` and `s2` have their `name` pointed to exactly the same memory location. If `s` contained any allocated data there, using it inside `s1` or `s2` after `delete` would lead to cataclysm.

Comment: Please notice s1 and s2 are between `new s` and `delete s`

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, but they are local variables, so they are valid and accessible as long as `main` executes and after `delete` they may still be used to perform further actions on (now) invalid memory. Perhaps such explanation was expected? As hypothetical employer, I would be very happy if my potential employee was aware of such things.

Comment: Given that `name` is a wild (uninitialized) pointer, and it's never dereferenced or freed, then we don't actually hit any Undefined Behaviour.  But then, why have that member at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
```

Tell the compiler the program will use some functions defined in the library iostream

```
using namespace std;
```

Tell the compiler to use the std namespace. Basically, we don't need to write "std." before functions defined in the std namespace anymore with this command.

```
class Student {
  private:
    char *name;
};
```

Define a new class named 'Student' which contains a single variable named 'name'.
'name' is private and thus can only be accessed by members of the class.
'name' is pointer to char and thus can be used to point to arrays of characters.

```
int main()
{
```

Start the definition of the main program, the entry point of our program

```
Student *s = new Student();
```

Define a pointer to a Student object named s.
'new Student()' allocates memory for a Student object.
s stores the address of the allocated memory.
Note: the variable 'name' in the Student class pointed by s is not initialized.

```
Student s1 = *s;
```

Define a new Student object s1 and initialize it by copying the Student object pointed by s. 
The variable 'name' in s1 copy the (not-initialized!) value of the variable 'name' in the Student class pointed by s.

```
Student s2;
```

Define a new Student object s2.
s2 is initialized by default.

```
s2 = s1;
```

initialize s2 by copying s1

```
delete s;
```

delete the Student object allocated in the memory space pointed by s

```
return 0;
```

end the program by returning 0 to the calling process